# I need the Domain of integration of a double integral

Tags: integral-domain

Giveing that I have a squere formed with the points **(1,0) , (0,1) , (-1,0) , (0,-1)** so basically a romb centerd in **O(0,0)** how do I find the domain of integration **D** ? I've started by giving the **x** his domain ( **-1 < x < 1** ) and getting the equations for each side of the romb , as I wrote them in the image , but now I am stuck ... I want to get a domain for **y** using the variable **x** .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is $\int_0^{1}\int_{x-1}^{1-x} dydx+\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{-x-1}^{x+1} dy dx$ or $\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|} dydx$.

Comment: And if i wanted to have only 1 integral from -1 < x < 1 what would the domain of y look like ?

Comment: Just draw vertical lines. For example when $0<x<1$ the $y$ coordinate ranges from $y=x-1$ on the edge of the rhombus below the $x-$ axis to the $y=1-x$ on the edge of the rhombus above the $x-$ axis. Basically you have to fix an $x$ and look at  the possible values for $y$.

Comment: If you want to avoid splitting the interval $(-1,1)$ you can write $\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|} dydx$.